# iOS wake up/interrupt the device with Swift

Tags: ios

I hope this question is fit for SE, but if not please tell me where I could move it and I'll do so gladly.   I'm currently building an iOS app and need to wake the device up/interrupt the current app when a "match booking request" is made, the behaviour I'm looking for is similar to what Skype uses when a call is inbound, the handset either wakes up or interrupts the current running app with the answer/end call interface.

I have never had experience with iOS, and the only solution I can think of is to poll the app and check for requests but I imagine this could be pretty intensive on power consumption,  I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to what technique I could use to achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app cannot run in the background the way you are expecting. Polling is not an option.

It looks like Skype is using [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) to wake up the phone.

Comment: Gotcha, thank-you Jeffery - I should make more of an effort to scour the dev library opposed to posts on Google!